# Is there any way to find out (at runtime) which entity has caused a ConstraintViolationException?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a (REST) application that handles CRUD operations initiated by a 3rd party, and basically my problem is in returning an easily understood error message in the case of a constraint violation. I'm using Hibernate (though JPA solutions would be better) and the ConstraintViolationException it throws is not terribly useful, it doesn't even have the name of the constraint that has been violated. I've so far been returning `constraintViolation.getSQLException().getMessage()` which returns a half decent message along the lines of `Duplicate entry '<value>' for key 2`.

The problem is a new requirement to improve the error returned to include *which* entity failed to commit as well as the value (and what kind of failure it was as a custom error code; DUPLICATE_VALUE, MISSING_FOREIGN_KEY, or something like that). Since the above string comes from the SQLException I assume it depends on the DB/driver, so while I *could* pick out '' from that string and search through every field in every object I just committed to try to find the right one it doesn't exactly seem the robust option (especially as we need to support multiple databases).

So is there any way I can find this information based on the information at hand? (Which is basically just the ConstraintViolationException w/SQLException and the object I tried to persist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why you should validate provided data in business logic rather than depending on Hibernate to do it. Web frameworks provide validation mechanisms for just this reason.

Comment: We use the Hibernate validation framework, but we can't connect to the database from it as far as I know. Also I'm not sure we'd want to as there are potentially thousands of committed records in a transaction. The fact of the matter is we must make the jump to the database to check if it's valid and those that aren't are going to be very rare; is it really worth the overhead of doing extra jumps to a (remote) database to check before committing? Even that doesn't seem likely to guarantee there won't be mid-air collisions.

Comment: Depending on the size of your database, this may not be a significant performance hit as Hiberate utilizes a cache.

Comment: The things in question are almost guaranteed not to be in the cache. This does however seem to be the only viable way to go. There's still the issue of a race condition to commit after checking, but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to capture that exception specifically and return a meaningful response, instead of generic exceptions and parsing it to understand , it's worth the effort to re-factor this. just my 2c's

Comment: Neither the SQLException or the ConstraintViolationException are proving me with much useful info, but I have access to both. I'm not sure what Exception you're suggesting I catch. Or how you think I should refactor for that matter.

Comment: The documentation gives  the constraint 

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/JDBCException.html

It does not give further details than that.

Comment: That's just a superclass of the exception I'm catching. I don't really follow what you mean.